# Yii Framework 2.0 check if it is a GET request from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

Working with Yii framework 2.0, I have an AJAX GET jQuery script that points to a function in a controller class.

```
$.get('localhost/website/index', {param: 'xxxx'}, function(returnedData){
    // some code here.....
}, 'json');
```

In the controller class I have a method as following that handles the AJAX GET request.

```
public function actionIndex() {
     $getParam = $_GET['param'];
     // echo $getParam is: 'xxxx'.

     // some other code here....

     echo json_encode(array());
}
```

Everything works fine when executing this AJAX GET jQuery script. But if I visit the link ***localhost/website/index*** manually on the web browser, I get the following error.

```
PHP Notice - ErrorException
Undefined index: param

// the code snippet is also being shown.....
```

I don't want any users to see this error in case they know this link and visit this link by accident or on purpose. If I use

```
if($_GET['param']){...}
```

I still get the error message on the browser. How can I solve that?

Comment: "I don't want any users to see this error in case they know this link and visit this link by accident or on purpose." — Why? You can't prevent users from seeing what you are sending to their browser. If the raw data isn't intended for the end users to look at directly, just avoid encouraging them from looking at it. They'll be able to see it if they really want to and you'll just waste your own time trying to stop them.

Answer (score 21):

You can check, that the request is an ajax request with [`isAjax`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$isAjax-detail):

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
if ($request->isAjax) {...}
```

Or you can check that the request is POST or GET

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {...}
if (Yii::$app->request->isGet) {...}
```

And always use isset() as well! :)

Comment: can I use post `ajax` request and `isPost` all at once ? @AdamFentosi

Comment: @Stfvns I haven't tested, but I couldn't see any problem with it. An XMLHttpRequest can be either a POST or a GET.

Answer (score 2):

easy way:

```
if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
    ...
}
```

right way:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Note that this depends on adding the non-standard x-requested-with header (which isn't a problem while you use jQuery since it adds it by default) and doesn't provide any *security*. It really isn't worth using this for anything other than deciding if you want to return JSON or an HTML document for a RESTful API.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your point. All I need is the above if-statement to hide the error message on the web browser if user visits the above link, because it is meant for an AJAX GET request.

Comment: When you send AJAX-request web-browser automatically adds header `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'xmlhttprequest'`. If you try to open page by URL -- browser don't add such header.

So, if condition `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'` is `true` -- this is AJAX-request, if `false` -- it is not.